Generalization error bound for Empirical Risk minimizer on Gaussian noisy data
I have datapoints that are sampled from a distribution $\mathbb{D}$. Each datapoint is a tuple $(t,y)$ of a time $t \in [0,T]$ that is sampled uniformly and a value $y(t) \sim u(t) + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_t^2)$. Where the $\sigma_t \in [0, \infty)$ can vary continuously with time $t$. And $\mathcal{N}$ is a Normal distribution, $u(t)$ is some deterministic function of time.
Assume now, I have an empirical risk minimizer, that is trying to learn from the data, by estimating the parameter $\Theta$. And outputs for each sampled $t$ a number $y'_{\Theta}(t)$.
For a set $S$ of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ sampled datapoints $(t_i, y_i)$, I define
the empirical risk as:
\begin{equation*}
L_{S} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_i - y'_{\Theta}(t_i))^2
\end{equation*}
Further, I define the true risk as:
\begin{equation*}
L_{\mathbb{D}} =\mathbb{E}_{(t,y) \sim \mathbb{D}}[(y - y'_{\Theta}(t))^2]
\end{equation*}
These definitions are from: https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/index.html. Now, I say that underfitting occurs, if the term $L_{S}$ is large, while overfitting occurs, if the term $L_{\mathbb{D}} - L_{S}$ is large. And I was asking myself, if it was possible to find bounds on $L_{\mathbb{D}} - L_{S}$ and $L_{S}$ for my particular distribution.
I am searching for something similar to Corollary 13.6 in the book, also possible with $L^1$ or $L^2$ regularization. But with the difference that I have random noise added. And my $y'_{\Theta}$ is not a convex function of $\Theta$.
Or, in the same vein something like Corollary 14.6 from the book https://cs.nyu.edu/~mohri/mlbook/. But my Gaussian distribution is unfortunately unbounded.
I am thankful for any help !

Bounds on $|L_{\mathbb D}-L_S|_2$ are usually called risk bounds. There is an expansive literature on them, using e.g. Rademacher complexity of Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension, although quite a lot is for classification. The book "Understanding Machine Learning" that you link seems to have a chapter 11 dedicated to regression. Theorem 1.1 therein seems like a step in the right direction.

Also, if you have not done so already, you can post you question on the statistics (Cross Validated) SE https://stats.stackexchange.com/. It is likely you will find people who can answer your question.

Hey, Thanks @ThomasLehéricy for your comment. Unfortunately, Theorem 1.1 uses the Hoeffdings inequality, which in turn uses boundedness of the random variables. The same holds for Bennet's and Bernstein's inequalities unfortunately. This is something that it not easy to get rid off.

In Theorem 1.1, any concentration inequality is suitable provided it works on the loss $L$. Here your losses have exponential tails, so you do have inequalities to replace Hoeffding. From there, could still adapt the proof. For instance in your case, if you assume a bound on the maximum of $|y’_\Theta - y|$, you can bound $\mathbb E[\exp(x L_S)]$ (first when $n=1$, then by independence for all $n$) and use Chernoff’s bound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound .

Okay, following your advice, if I set $Z:=\mathbb{E}[\ell(h)] - \ell(h,(t,y))$ for a fixed hypothesis $h$. Then, bounding $\mathbb{E}[e^{xZ}] \leq e^{x \mathbb{E}[\ell]} \cdot \mathbb{E}{(t,y) \sim D} [e^{-x \ell(h,(t,y)}]$. The second term in the product, I can now bound by: $\int{0}^{T} \frac{1}{T} \int_{ - \infty}^{\infty} f_{\sigma_{t}}(y') \cdot e^{-x (h(t) - u(t) - y')^2} dy' dt$. Where $f_{\sigma_t}$ is the Gaussian density. And use $(h(t) - u(t) - y')^2 = (h(t) - u(t))^2 - 2\cdot (h(t)-u(t))\cdot y' + (y')^2$. Is that what you meant ?

Yes, it is indeed what I meant. Provided that $\sup_t \sigma_t$ is finite, you should get a finite value for $|x|$ small enough.

Thanks for the help ! I was able to obtain a bound of $\mathbb{E}{(t,y) \sim \mathbb{D}}[L{\mathbb{D}}(\mathcal{A}(t,y) - L_{y}(\mathcal{A}(t,y)] \leq C_1 \cdot (1+ C_2 \cdot \text{max}_t \sigma_t) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. I hope I find the time to post the whole proof in here. Would you like to be cited as giving me the idea in my thesis ? :D

go for it, happy to help :) Also, the usual formulation in the PAC framework (like theorem 1.1) is something of the form: with probability at least $1-\delta$, we have $L_{\mathbb D} \leq L_S + \sqrt{\frac{a - b\ln \delta}n}$. You could get something similar from Markov's inequality applied to your bound, but the dependence in $\delta$ would not be as good.

Yeah, so I actually first derived $\mathbb{P}(Z \geq a) \leq K \cdot (1+a \cdot \frac{max_{t} \sigma_t}{2 \cdot D}) \cdot e^{- \frac{n a^2}{4 D}} $ and then used $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X \geq a) da - \int_{- \infty}^{0} \mathbb{P}(X \leq a) da \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X \geq a) da$. So I could arrive at a better bound I think
